# Apply xsl:template not to all elements but to half

Tags: xslt

I have an XSL template which processes an XML document into a test in Gherkin. For every  element in the XML I'm producing and Gherkin line such as

```
And I fill in the "check-temp" field with "23"
```

That's fine, but I want to only produce this line for the first 20 instances of , then do some other output, then pick up where I left off. Something like this, using imaginary syntax:

```
<xsl:for-each select="formline" [0..20]> 
...other stuff...
<xsl:for-each select="formline" [21..40]>
```

Related to this, can XSL "know" how many matches are found?

SOLVED: Thanks for your contributions. Here's what I've done:

```
# Fill in first 'half' of form 
<xsl:for-each select="formline[not(position() > 20)]">                           
<xsl:for-each select="formentrycontext">And I fill in "<xsl:value-of select="formentry/@id"/>" with "xxx"
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
# Check first 'half' of form 
<xsl:for-each select="formline[not(position() > 20)]">                           
<xsl:for-each select="formentrycontext">And the "<xsl:value-of select="formentry/@id"/>" field should contain "xxx"
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
# Fill in second 'half' of form 
<xsl:for-each select="formline[position() > 20 and not(position() > last())]">                           
<xsl:for-each select="formentrycontext">And I fill in "<xsl:value-of select="formentry/@id"/>" with "xxx"
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
# Check second 'half' of form 
<xsl:for-each select="formline[position() > 20 and not(position() > last())]">                           
<xsl:for-each select="formentrycontext">And I fill in "<xsl:value-of select="formentry/@id"/>" with "xxx"
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I'm not using the apply-templates as I want to apply one transform at one time and then another transform later to the same data. Maybe there is a way to do it but this works perfectly for me so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach could work for you:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="formline[not(position() > 20)]"/>
...other stuff...
<xsl:apply-templates select="formline[position() > 20 and not(position() > 40)]"/>
```

You need to put the code to display the formline data into a template like this

```
<xsl:template match="formline">
```

so you only need one that is used every time again. This will work if the formline elements in the XML data are not mixed with other elements so their position can be used.
Edit: I like to use rather ">" and "not( > )" than ">" and "& lt;" or even "& gt;" and "& lt;" but thats just fashion.
Edit: Corrected according to comment of Michael Kay (thank you, I was not aware of that)

Comment: That second example should read `formline[position() > 20 and not(position() > 40)]`. The value of `position()` is relative to the sequence being filtered.

Comment: Bang on. My formline elements are mixed with others, but in this case I don't have to be too fussy about where the break between the first and second 'halves' are, I can hardcode the 20.

Answer (score 1):

> Related to this, can XSL "know" how many matches are found?

**Yes, use the [`count()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-count) function**:

```
 count(formline[not(position() > 20)])
```

**Alternatively, inside a matching template of `xsl:for-each` one can use the [`last()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-last) function**.

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="formline[not(position() > 20)]"/>
```

**and in**

```
 <xsl:template match="formline">
   <xsl:value-of select="last()"/>
   <!-- Your processing here -->
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hey, I wish I could accept two answers, your mention of the last function was very useful!